# What's the difference in jquery.tmpl and jquery.tmplPlus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm thinking of starting to use the jQuery template engine in my projects.

What is the difference in these two?  Also, is it a good time to start using tmpl since it's still beta?

Comment: I don't know, it's on the Git: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Comment: looks like un documented extra features. I think it's just an extension that does some extra stuff but is not part of the core and is not documented / tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is rather trivial, according to this comment in the first lines of jquery-tmplPLus.js:

```
Additional templating features or support for more advanced/less common scenarios.
```

Comment: I saw that, but it's so vague... I was hoping for some incite.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't looking for some incite. I was looking for some insight.

Answer (score 2):

jquery.tmpl has been deprecated and will not be developed in the present form. The jQuery UI team has taken control over the templating project and will start from scratch again.

More info here
http://blog.jquery.com/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/
http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/37898666/Template

Unfortunately I'm relying on the version of jquery.tmpl that is out in the wild now. Instead of changing templating library twice, I'm waiting for the new template library to come out of the jQuery UI team.

Comment: Even though this is good information, this doesn't really answer this question. Maybe make this an answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842906/jquery-tmpl-and-datalink-beta

Comment: Thanks! I've cross posted the answer to the question you suggested. Trying to earn my reputation points while never finding a question that hasn't already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would stay away from both. jquery.tmpl is a deadend, and it seems you can wait a long time for jquery to provide templating... (http://www.borismoore.com/2011/10/jquery-templates-and-jsviews-roadmap.html) Personally, I made the switch to knockoutjs. It uses jquery.tmpl in the 1.2.4 version, and the 1.3 beta already has its own templating. As from what I've been reading, it looks like the migration will not be very painful...

Another path you can go is backbone js, though I didn't know very much about it.

Comment: Why is jQuery Templates a deadend?  It still works wonderfully and it is elegant (unlike Knockout).  Don't get me wrong, knockout has its benefits but it may be too big a tool for a simple templating job.  And, after all, if jQuery Templates are good enough for Knockout, aren't they good enough for your project?

Comment: If a product is no longer maintained, I call that a good reason to call it deadend. Furthermore, also Knockout stepped away from jQuery templates, and I'm glad they did, because I consider it way more designer-friendly than the mustache/handlebars frameworks out there.