# jQuery tmpl and DataLink beta

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

Does anybody know when jQuery.tmpl and Data Link will come out of beta? There is a lot of people saying that it was going to be part of the 1.5 core. Are these 'offical' plugins dead?

Comment: Regarding `.tmpl()`, there's a note here: [The jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta. It is no longer being actively developed or maintained.](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl/).

Comment: This looks like a pretty good answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jquery.tmpl has been deprecated and will not be developed in the present form. The jQuery UI team has taken control over the templating project and will start from scratch again.

More info here http://blog.jquery.com/2011/04/16/official-plugins-a-change-in-the-roadmap/ http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/37898666/Template

Unfortunately I'm relying on the version of jquery.tmpl that is out in the wild now. Instead of changing templating library twice, I'm waiting for the new template library to come out of the jQuery UI team.